# rails 2.3 named_scope nested hash in conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Im really really new to ruby/ruby on rails and was given a model class that looks like this. I just want ask why is it giving me odd number list for Hash error when I try to call Ranks.search_word("Jagger")

Im using Rails 2.3.5/ActiveRecord 2.3.5

```
class Ranks < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'CM_GT_RANK'
  set_primary_key 'rank_id'

  has_one :character_atlas, :class_name => "CharAtlas", :foreign_key => "char_id_db"
  has_one :player_records, :class_name => "PlayerRecord", :foreign_key => "char_id"

  default_scope  :joins => :character_atlas,
                 :order => "rank asc"
  named_scope :search_word,
    lambda{ |keyword|
      {
        if keyword.present?
          {:conditions => { :CM_CHAR_ATLAS => {:char_name => keyword }} }
        else
          {}
        end
      }
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional Pair of curly brackets which are not required. Try:

```
named_scope :search_word, lambda{ |keyword|
  if keyword.present?   
    {:conditions => { :CM_CHAR_ATLAS => {:char_name => keyword }} }
  else
    {}
  end
}
```

Comment: don't worry. have fun on stackoverflow ;)